# haskell parser combinator infinite loop

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators

I'm trying to write a simple parser via Haskell, but stuck at an infinite loop.
the code is:

```
import Control.Applicative (Alternative, empty, many, (<|>))

data Parser a = Parser {runParser :: String -> [(a, String)]}

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> [(f x', s') | (x', s') <- p s]

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x = Parser $ \s -> [(x, s)]
  (Parser pf) <*> (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> [(f' x, ss') | (f', ss) <- pf s, (x, ss') <- p ss]

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser $ \s -> []
  (Parser p1) <|> (Parser p2) = Parser $ \s ->
    case p1 s of
      [] -> p2 s
      xs -> xs

singleSpaceParser :: Parser Char
singleSpaceParser = Parser $ \s ->
  ( case s of
      x : xs -> if x == ' ' then [(' ', xs)] else []
      [] -> []
  )

multiSpaceParser :: Parser [Char]
multiSpaceParser = many singleSpaceParser
```

I just load this file in ghci, and run:

```
runParser multiSpaceParser "  123"
```

I expect it to get `[("   ", "123")]`, but actually it got an infinite loop

I used trace to debug, and it seems that `many` is wrong

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: `many` deals with `Alternative`, so it means it will first try a `singleSpaceParser`, if that fails, it will attempt another `singleSpaceParser` etc.

Comment: so the problem is multiSpaceParser will call infinite `singleSpaceParser`? why it will attempt another `singleSpaceParser` if the first `singleSpaceParser` fails?

Comment: It's a rather subtle laziness-induced problem. If you replace `data` by `newtype`, it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume

```
many p = (:) <$> p <*> many p <|> pure []
```

and consider the call

```
many singleSpaceParser "  123"
```

(The string does not actually matter here, the `many singleSpaceParser` call will always loop.)

One reduction step yields

```
   ((:) <$> singleSpaceParser <*> many singleSpaceParser <|> pure []) "  123"
```

Now observe that, in order to reduce the call to `(<|>)`, we have to evaluate both arguments of `(<|>)` to be of the shape `Parser ...`.

Let's consider doing that for `(:) <$> singleSpaceParser <*> many singleSpaceParser`. As both `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` are `infixl 4`, this is an application of `<*>` at the outermost level.

But now observe that in order to reduce `(<*>)`, we again have to evaluate both arguments of `(<*>)` to be of the shape `Parser ...`, so in particular the recursive call `many singleSpaceParser`.

This is where we get the infinite loop.

By switching `data` to `newtype` (or alternatively, at least avoiding aggressively pattern-matching on the `Parser` constructor in all the second arguments), these problems can be avoided.

Comment: after changing `data` to `newtype` I solve the problem, thank you so much :)

Comment: Then do `deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad) via StateT String []`

Comment: You can also make `<*>` lazier with - `pf <*> p = Parser $ \s -> [(f' x, ss') | (f', ss) <- runParser pf s, (x, ss') <- runParser p ss]`

Comment: Alternatively, make `<*>` lazier with `~`:  `~(Parser pf) <*> ~(Parser p) = ...`